# When is 'this' required?

Tags: c++

Is the `this` pointer ever required? I guess you'd need it if you were functionally passing around the instance of the class pointed to by `this`.  But in terms of setting/retrieving/calling/whatever members, is `this` always optional?

I've tagged this C++ because that's the language I'm specifically wondering about, but if someone can confirm that the construct is the same for Java and other OO languages that use a `this` pointer, it'd be appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need it when you have a local variable that has the exact same name as the member variable. In this case, the local variable is said to shadow the member variable. To get to the member variable in this situation, you *must* use `this`.

Some people consider it good practice to explicitly mention that the variable you are modifying is a member variable by using `this` all the time, but this is not always the case.

Comment: For C++ your last consideration is true, but for Java or C#, it's not always the convention

Comment: This is why you always name your member variables differently from your local ones, e.g. `m_myVar` or `myVar_` and so on. Since using `this` isn't enforced most projects opt to force a naming standard on the member variables instead.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's good form to use `this` all the time. Only use it if there are shadowing names. Usually the shadows can be avoided, too.

Comment: Strictly this is not necessary in this case, since you can also say classname::variable

Comment: @Oleksi - I was also wondering if it was good practice to use `this`.  I guess there is some debate there haha.  Thanks for the helpful answer.

Answer (score 20):

There's three cases I can think of:

When you simply want to pass a pointer to the current class:

```
class B;
struct A {
    B* parent_;
    A(B* parent) : parent_(parent) {}
};

struct B {
    A* a;
    B() : a(new A(this)) {}
};
```

---

In a constructor or member function, where a member is shadowed by an argument:

```
struct A {
    int a;
    void set_a(int a) { this->a = a; }
};
```

Here, the member variable "a" is shadowed by the argument "a", so `this->` is used to access the member instead of the argument.

(example above edited to be a function rather than constructor, since you wouldn't normally assign this way in a constructor)

---

When accessing a public/protected member variable or function in a base class of a template class

```
template <class T>
struct A {
    int a;
};

template <class T>
struct B : public A<T> {
    int f() { return this->a; }
}
```

here, `a` alone would not be a dependent name, so the compiler would expect to find a declaration of it in `B` or a base of `B` that does not depend on `T`. Adding `this->` makes the lookup dependent on the type of `this`, and since `this` is a dependent type, the lookup of `a` is deferred until `f()` is instantiated.

One could write `return A::a` instead of `return this->a`, but in the presence of multiple bases, whether direct or indirect, using `this->` is more flexible. This alternative syntax is also limited to member variables and non-virtual functions - if it is used with a virtual function, it the function will be called directly instead of doing virtual function call.

Comment: You can always use the classname::variablename for accessing it, as such this can be used for it, but it is not necessary.

Comment: @PlasmaHH Yeah, I was interpreting the question as "in what situations is writing 'this' not redundant" rather than "in what situation is writing 'this' the only way of achieving something"

Comment: In fact only your first example is correct, for the other two the use of `this` is optional. In your second example, using ctor initializer list is idiomatic C++ and won't have the ambiguity problem, e.g. `A::A(int a) : a(a) {}` is valid and not ambiguous (for the compiler at least).

Comment: @AndreasMagnusson Both #2 and #3 would not compile if `this->` was simply omitted. For #3 there is an alternative syntax that can be more cumbersome to use, and for #2.. of course you can write the trivial example a better way, I could've made the example more complex to make accessing A in the body required, but that would have made the answer harder to understand.

Comment: @je4d, the third one doesn't require `this`. It would if the base class was dependent on a template parameter.

Comment: For #3 `this` can be required as well, namely if a virtual member function is to be called. Then `C::f()` and `this->f()` may not be equivalent.

Comment: @avakar: Yes, for example with `struct B: T` and `B<A>`.

Comment: @avakar Oops.. I was trying for the simplest example, and lazily figured that it would be needed even in this case because a specialization could have a different set of bases - but of course that code wouldn't get used for said specialization. I'll update it to reflect.

Comment: @je4d: As I said your #2 could (and should) be written using an initializer list instead. Besides, anyone caring about code readability would name their member variables in a *special* way. The recommended style in C++ is `memberVar_`. In #3 `a` isn't really a dependent name. As has already been stated `B` should derive from its template class for that to be the case (and at least VS2010 accepts it with just an `a` (without `this->` or the preferable `T::` before).

Comment: @AndreasMagnusson I've avoided good style to construct an example of the language rules. When I answer a question about coding style, you may critique my coding style. The details of overly permissive compilers (VS, pre-3.4 gcc) are irrelevant when the OP wasn't even about templates, so I didn't mention them.

Comment: @Philipp +1 for remembering the other use of `T::member`! Incorporated above.

Comment: @je4d: My impression was that the OP asked for an example where `this` was required. Otherwise you might as well say use `this` when you access *any* members. So no, my critique wasn't about style it was about you missing the core of the OP's question.

Comment: I found this question in situation #3. I really don't see why `A<T>::base_function()` is preferable to `this->base_function()`. In particular,  I can't tell if certain comments are trying to help me write better or more standard code, or just hassle the original answerer about (perhaps inferior) code in which `this` is not _necessary_ but it is _desirable_.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus I'd recommend ignoring the entire conversation with Andreas. I apologise for not concluding it, but it seemed petty and I got bored. I think I interpreted the question more broadly than others, and stylistic issues got dragged in as collateral damage. The question wasn't about what's _better_, so you're unlikely to get a useful discussion on that topic here.

Comment: Now, on the question of `A<T>::base_function()` and `this->base_function()`, neither is preferable, they are different. You should choose whichever better expresses what you are trying to achieve. The `this->` variant is usually what you want, it's a direct way of getting around the dependent name problem. Using `A<T>::` has additional effects: it won't look for a function named `base_function` in `B` first, and won't invoke virtual dispatch even if `base_function` is virtual.

Answer (score -4):

sometimes "this" is required, maybe when you are passing your object to another function.
look at this c# code( for opening a modal form with this parent)

```
Form1 f = new Form();
f.ShowDialog(this);
```

Comment: This does not look like C++.

Comment: The question is about C++