# Unity tutorial- Gameobject won't destroy

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, destroy

I'm following a Udemy 2D tutorial in Unity to create a 2D pixel game. Language is C#. I am simply copying down the code because I am unfamiliar with coding, however I copied down the code to a T and I am having issues with one of my GameObjects. The objective is to destroy my Sword gameobject every time I launch it, otherwise a bunch of copies show up in my hierarchy. The copies don't destroy themselves.
If I'm reading this correctly, which I may not because I am not a programmer, this stems from another bit of code that states the Character cannot move while the Sword is being launched, however this check box does not toggle back to canMove= true, leaving the character stuck in place. While canMove = false, the Sword gameobject won't destroy. It might be easier to explain with my code.

This is my Player canMove code:

```
void Attack()
    {
        canMove = false;
        GameObject newSword = Instantiate(sword, transform.position, sword.transform.rotation);
        #region //SwordRotation
        int swordDir = anim.GetInteger("dir");
        if(swordDir == 0) 
    {
            newSword.transform.Rotate(0, 0, 0);
            newSword.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(Vector2.up * thrustPower);
    }
        else if (swordDir == 1)
    {
            newSword.transform.Rotate(0, 0, 180);
            newSword.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(Vector2.up * -thrustPower);
    }
        else if (swordDir == 2)
    {
            newSword.transform.Rotate(0, 0, 90);
            newSword.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(Vector2.right * -thrustPower);
    }
        else if (swordDir == 3)
    {
            newSword.transform.Rotate(0, 0, -90);
            newSword.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(Vector2.right * thrustPower);
    }
        #endregion


    }

    void Movement()
    {
        if (!canMove)
            return;
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
        { transform.Translate(0, speed * Time.deltaTime, 0); anim.SetInteger("dir", 0); anim.speed = 1; }
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
        { transform.Translate(0, -speed * Time.deltaTime, 0); anim.SetInteger("dir", 1); anim.speed = 1; }
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        { transform.Translate(-speed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0); anim.SetInteger("dir", 2); anim.speed = 1; }
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        { transform.Translate(speed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0); anim.SetInteger("dir", 3); anim.speed = 1; }
        else
            anim.speed = 0;
    }
```

And my Sword code:

```
public class Sword : MonoBehaviour
{
    float timer = .15f;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        timer -= Time.deltaTime;
    if (timer <= 0)
    {
        GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<Player>().canMove = true;
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your sword enabled/active? Is it greyed out in the hierarchy?

Comment: @ErikOverflow Yes it is enabled and not greyed out

Answer (score 0):

I checked the Sword code on my environment, and the timer seems to be working OK.
If anything, check that the Player object has the tag "Player" assigned to it. The code might be stopping there, if it's unable to find the desired object.

The place to assign the tag can be found in the inspector, under a drop-down next to the **Tag** option.

[image]

If you've already done this, check if there are any other objects with the "Player" tag assigned to it. **FindGameObjectWithTag** will only look for 1 object, which may not be the one you were looking for.
If in doubt, place in these lines somewhere in your code:

```cs
GameObject player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
Debug.Log(player.name);
```

This should give back the name of the object you were trying to find.
If this comes back as null, it's not managing to find it.

Answer (score 0):

`Destroy(gameObject);` in your Sword code. Change it to `Destroy(this.gameObject);`

The sword is now gone.

Comment: The `this` is irrelevant. The context of any code is already `this` and both `this.gameObject` and `gameObject` refer to the same thing (unless [a local variable gets involved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9608762/when-is-this-required)).