# How to define default constructor and user-defined constructor in the same line?

Tags: c++, class, object, inheritance, constructor

In my university class we are messing around with inheritance, though my professor's code confused me and seemed to be a little off.

```
class Circle
{
  protected:
    double radius;
  public:
    Circle(double = 1.0);
    double calcval();
};

Circle::Circle(double r)
{
  radius = r;
}
```

Here she is creating a default constructor within the class then creating a separate user-defined constructor outside of the class. When I initially saw this I thought there has to be a way to do this more efficiently and in return take up less space, making the code more readable.

After some searching online I found some resources at which I tried, though I am still getting some errors. Here is the constructors for class "Circle" which I tried.

```
class Circle
{
    protected:
        double radius;

    public:
        double calcVal();

        Circle(double r = 1.0) : radius(r) {}
};
```

Is this correct? I am trying to make the default constructor set radius = 1.0 and have a constructor that sets radius = to 'r', the user input.

We also have another derived class "Cylinder" which I tried doing something similar but received errors.

Here is my professor's implementation.

```
class Cylinder : public Circle
{
  protected:
    double length;
    double volume;
  public:       
    Cylinder(double r, double len);
    double calcval();
};

Cylinder::Cylinder(double r, double len){
    length =len;
    this->radius =r;
}
```

Then here is what I attempted.

```
class Cylinder : public Circle
{
    private:
        double length;
        double volume;
    public:
        double calcVal();

        Cylinder(double r, double len) : length(len) this->radius(r) {}
};
```

However, I get an error on the beginning of "this", which says "expected a "{"."

How, if possible, would I create a default constructor and user-defined constructor in the same line for readability and cleaner code? Thank you so much for reading.

My overall implementation for your convenience. :)

```
class Circle
{
    protected:
        double radius;

    public:
        double calcVal();

        Circle(double r = 1.0) : radius(r) {}
};

double Circle::calcVal()
{
    return (PI * (radius * radius));
}

class Cylinder : public Circle
{
    private:
        double length;
        double volume;
    public:
        double calcVal();

        Cylinder(double r, double len) : length(len) this->radius(r) {}
};

double Cylinder::calcVal()
{
    return (length * PI * (r * r));
}
```

Comment: Sorry I worded it poorly. But is there a way to do these two constructors within the same line to take up less space and make the code more readable? The error for the cylinder class is the one I'm concerned about.

Comment: What two constructors do you mean? I see only one in each class, both user-defined.

Comment: Less space often doesn't equate to more readable. What you are looking for is `Cylinder(double r, double len) :  Circle(r), length(len){}` so you can call the base constructor to do the dirty work with `r` and ensure that ALL of the work `Circle` could be doing is done.

Comment: And praise <insert deity of choice> that the member initializer list is being covered. You might have one of the *good* instructors.

Comment: @user4581301 "*And praise ... that the member initializer list is being covered*" - doubtful, considering that the professor's own code is NOT using the member initialization list at all. This sounds more like the OP has discovered MILs on their own and is experimenting with them.

Comment: Awww <expletive deleted>. Oh well, the asker picked it up from somewhere. I'll take that as a win.

Comment: A minor comment here. Geometry imho is a terribly wrong way to explain inheritance and this is an example of that. A cylinder is _not_ a circle, it's nowhere near being that. A circle has area, a cylinder does not (well, unless you define it as a 2D bounding metric, in which case it's _different_ than what a circle would provide). So this example - that your teacher gave you -  is perhaps not the best way to learn it. This happens sometimes during University and you have to live with it, but I guess it's worth to know about the issues.

Comment: Even though you ***could*** write the constructor in one line, adding line breaks between the parameter list and between each of the member initializers can increase readability tremendously.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Here she is creating a default constructor within the class then creating a separate user-defined constructor outside of the class.

No, she is **declaring** the default constructor inside the class's declaration, and then **defining** the *body* of that constructor outside of the class declaration.  This is perfectly legal and correct code.

> I am still getting some errors

That is because you have mistakes in your code.

> Here is the constructors for class "Circle" which I tried ... Is this correct?

In that example, yes.

> We also have another derived class "Cylinder" which I tried doing something similar but received errors ... Then here is what I attempted ... However, I get an error on the beginning of "this", which says "expected a "{"."

Since `radius` is a member of `Circle`, you should let `Circle`'s constructor initialize `radius`. Don't do that in your derived `Cylinder`'s constructor. But, you are not calling `Circle`'s constructor yourself, so the compiler will call it for you, passing in its default argument value.

You are also missing a `,` in your `Cylinder`'s constructor member initialization list, which is a syntax error.

Try this instead:

```
Cylinder(double r, double len) : Circle(r), length(len) {}
```

---

Now, that being said, there are some other things worth pointing out in your code.

Your `Cylinder` class has a `volume` member that is never initialized or used, so it should be removed completely.

Inside of `Cylinder::calcVal()`, `r` is undefined. It is a local variable in the `Circle` and `Cylinder` constructors only.  You need to use the `radius` member instead (just like how `Circle::calcVal()` does, and how `Cylinder::calcVal()` is using the `length` member instead of the `len` constructor argument), eg:

```
return (length * PI * (radius * radius));
```

You are declaring `double calcVal();` in both classes, but `Circle::calcVal()` is not marked as `virtual`, so `Cylinder::calcVal()` will not override it.  If you were to ever make a `Circle*`/`Circle&` refer to a `Cylinder` object and then call `calcVal()` on that, only `Circle::calcVal()` would be called, not `Cylinder::calcVal()`.  So, make `Circle::calcVal()` be virtual, eg:

```
virtual double calcVal();
```

And for good measure, `Cylinder` should then mark its `calcVal()` as `override`:

```
double calcVal() override;
```

Since you want to reduce complexity in your classes, you can inline `calcVal()` in both classes, eg:

```
class Circle
{
    protected:
        double radius;

    public:
        virtual double calcVal() { return (PI * (radius * radius)); }

        Circle(double r = 1.0) : radius(r) {}
};

class Cylinder : public Circle
{
    private:
        double length;

    public:
        double calcVal() override { return (length * PI * (radius * radius)); }

        Cylinder(double r, double len) : Circle(r), length(len) {}
};
```

And then, since `Circle::calcVal()` and `Cylinder::calcVal()` are both calculating the same `PI * radius * radius` value, where `Cylinder` is just multiplying the result by `length`, you can actually call `Circle::calcVal()` inside of `Cylinder::calcVal()` to do the common work, eg:

```
double calcVal() override { return (length * Circle::calcVal());
```

Comment: Okay that makes a lot of sense thank you. However on the next line I have:
`double Cylinder::calcVal()
{
    return (length * PI * (r * r));
}`

It says r isn't defined, shouldn't it be defined as a data member from the constructor or am I missing something?

Comment: @Yeonari Correct, it is undefined, because `r` is a local variable in the constructor only. You need to use the `radius` member instead (which was initialized from `r`): `return (length * PI * (radius * radius));` Just like you are using the `length` member instead of the `len` constructor argument.

Comment: Oh you're right I just noticed, it was actually a typo after looking at my professor's code haha. 1 last thing, in her version of the cylinder constructor she has `this -> radius = r` In the version you are recommending, do I have to worry about whether I am using `this` or not? I'm confused by her usage since from what I know `this` is commonly used to access the object's data member instead of the local variable, usually when they are the same name. But that doesnt' seem to apply in this case from what I see?

Comment: @Yeonari The professor's use of `this` is correct, but redundant. She is using it to access the inherited data member, not the local variable. In general, you should avoid using `this` explicitly, except when [it is actually required](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9608903/65863).