Member variable in base class with the type of a template argument equal to array of size that depends on sub-class template argument not accessible
This does not compile:
template <class T>
struct Base {
  T m_data;
};
template <int size>
struct Sub : public Base<int[size]> {
  int f() { return m_data[0]; }
};

The error is use of undeclared identifier 'm_data' in the function body of f, both in clang and gcc.
If I replace int[size] by int[7], it compiles as I expect (but of course I need the template argument to be int[size].
If I replace return m_data[0] by return Base<int[size]>::m_data[0], it compiles too. That solves the practical problem for me.
See https://godbolt.org/z/zv39dWeEG
Even if my practical problem is solved, can anyone explain why int[size] but not int[7] makes m_data appear to be invisible in Sub?

Try this->m_data

Look for example at https://stackoverflow.com/a/9608903
